# Django redirects after ajax request

Tags: django, ajax

I want to make a school site, where you  must enter your invite code before you can register. I want to validate this code with an ajax POST request, but when I try to make request to validate view, it's redirecting to the page with **JSON** code.
**My AJAX**:

```
    {%extends "base.html"%}
    
    {%block content%}
    
    <script>
        $('#code_form').on('submit', function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            let form = evt.target
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: "POST",
                data: {'code': $('input[name="code"]')},
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': "{{csrf_token}}"},
                success: function(data){
                    window.location.href = data.url;
                    let status = JSON.parse(data)['ok']
                    if(status){
                        console.log('Good code');//This not executing
                    }else{
                        console.log('Bad code');//this too
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
    
    
    
    <form method = "POST" id = "code_form" action="{%url 'reg:submit'%}">
        {%csrf_token%}
        Enter your invite code: {{form.code}}<br>
        <button  id = "submit">Continue</button>
    </form>
    
    {%endblock%}
```

**Views.py**:

```
from .forms import StartF #form for code (contains only one field)
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

#here must be one more view, but it works fine

def submit(request):
    code = request.POST.get('code')
    data = {}
    try:
        user = Unregistered.objects.all().get(pk = code)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        data['ok'] = False
    else:
        data['ok'] = True

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**My urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

app_name = 'reg'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.start, name='start'), #that one view
    url(r'^ajax/submit/$', views.submit, name='submit'),#this view works not fine.
    
]
```

This is what it returned (ok = false, because i've inputted wrong code):
[image: Error page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure that you include jquery.js into your html file
2. put your code where you work with ajax into `$( document ).ready`

   ```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    ...
        $('#code_form').on('submit', function(evt){
        ...
        }
    ...
    }
   ```

Comment: i'll try, jquery included in base.html

Comment: Fixed problem, thank you so much! adding $(document).ready(...) helped me!!!!